# How to print json data with php?

Tags: php, json

Hi all here is my php code for json string

```
$or_details = '{"Details":[{"ID":"1781","shiiping_country":"US","shipping_first_name":"test","shipping_last_name":"test","shipping_company":"test","shipping_address_1":"test","shipping_address_2":"test","shipping_city":"test","shipping_state":"NJ","order_date":"","shipping_post_code":"12345","email":"srathod@gmail.com","phone":"1234567890","billing_country":"US","billing_first_name":"test","billing_last_name":"test","billing_company":"test","billing_address_1":"test","billing_address_2":"test","billing_city":"test","billing_state":"NJ","billing_post_code":"12345","payment_method":"Authorize.net","order_tax":"29.4","order_total":"449.4","delivery_date":"14-05-2014","Dumpster":"DriveWay"}],"items":[{"name":"Handicap Accessible Porta Potty","quantity":"1","price":"420"}]}';
```

Now i want to print ID. So how to do this. i have tried below code

```
$json = json_decode($or_details);
    echo $or_details['Details'].[ID];
```

Please let me know where i am wrong.

Comment: `$json = json_decode($or_details,true); echo $json['Details']['ID'];`

Comment: Try: `echo $json['Details']['ID'];`

Comment: Not helpfull.it prints nothing

Comment: `Details` is an array.  It might have more than one `ID`.

Comment: Details is an array?? what do you want to say bro?

Comment: you're decoding into `$json`, but still trying to use the original `$or_details` string for your echoes... problem?

Comment: `$json = json_decode($or_details); echo $json->Details[0]->ID;`